# Visual Studio 2012 Pro C# - how to update xsd for newly created columns in db table

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Please bear with me as I give a little history, then I will get to the problem:

I am rewriting a web app in Visual Studio 2012 Professional using C# and SQL Server 2012 Express.  I am creating new pages / logic but am reusing the data access objects from the old app, which was written in VS2008 and SQL Server 2008 Express by another developer years ago.  I got a backup of the db from the SQL Server 2008 db server and restored into the SQL Server 2012 db server.

Most everything works fine in the new application, but I have recently added a few columns to the Contacts table in SQL Server and now I am stuck at how to update the .xsd and related files for Contacts.  When I said that I reused the data access objects from the old app, what I meant was that I simply copied all of the .xsd, .xsc, .xss, .xsx and designer.cs files for Contacts and other objects from the old project (VS2008) to the new (VS2012).

I think all of these .xs* files are auto-generated when you use a data source configuration wizard or something in Visual Studio?  The problem is that I just copied the files into the new project to get the code behind working so that I could get and update data. But now I must update these files some how so they may be aware of the newly added columns, and I think I have to, in this new project, add a new Data Source?  I don't want to perform surgery by updating the files manually, that could get messy I would think...

I can probably figure out how to add the data source, but my concern is will that process complete successfully considering the existence of the files already?   Should I remove all of the .xs* files I copied in and add the datasource so it will recreate all those files again, and with the new columns?  What should I do?  I have backed up my new project in case something goes terribly wrong, so I can torpedo this project as many times as I need to until I get it right!

Thx in advance and thanks for reading this far.

Comment: Here is an update.  My VS2012 solution contains 5 projects.  4 of them are class libraries (DLL), and then there is the main web application.  I have read in many places that to add a datasource, go to Project > Add New Data Source.  Well, this menu option appears when I select any of the 4 class library projects and then go to that menu option.  Yet the Add New Data Source menu subitem is not available under Projects when I have the main web application selected, and it is web application that I need to update informing it of the new db columns in the xsd files.

Comment: I might also mention that the Target .NET Framework for all 5 projects is 3.5.

Comment: I did find resolution last night and today. And that was to manually add the columns into the DataTables themselves on the Typed DataSet surface! Simply right click, add column, give it the same name as the newly added column in the db table, and in properties set the datatype and default value. I also needed to make updates to the DataConnection.cs class adding SqlParameters for the new columns. Also, the sql statements for the select, insert, update, delete operations are kept in a DataConnection.resx file, and I needed to add the new columns in update and select statements.